# Cant get rid of a lot of whitespace at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

pretty new to coding, this is the first proper website I am trying to code. And i can't seem to get rid of whitespace at the bottom? i saw some of the divs are down where the whitespace is? But they are displaying where it isn't whitespace? Very weird I can't seem to fix the issue and did not find anything on the internet that could help me solving this issue. Please help. Would be very appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfolio03.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="Bar">
      <img src="Bar.png">
    </div>

    <div class="bakgrunn">
      </div>

    <div class="logoS">
      <p>S</p>
    </div>

    <span class="logoO">
    </span>

    <div class="home">
      <p>home</p>
    </div>

    <div class="work">
      <p>work</p>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
      <p>about</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hi">
      <h1>Hi There!<h1>
    </div>

    <div class="Bilde">
      <img src="Vector.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="workOverskrift">
      <p>work</p>
    </div>

    <div class="appdesign">
      <p>appdesign</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Hitesh">
      <img src="Hitesh.png">
    <div class="blurHitesh">
        <img src="Blur Hitesh.png">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="arrowHøyre">
      <img src="Component 3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="arrowVenstre">
      <img src="Component 4.svg">
    </div>

    <div class="aboutOverskrift">
      <p>about</p>
    </div>

    <div class="aboutTekst">
      <p>.</p>
    </div>

    </body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
`html,body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 .Bar img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1385px;
 height: 100px;
 z-index: 10;

 }

 .bakgrunn {
  position: relative;
  width: 1410px;
  height: 3840px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #F2F1FF;


  z-index: -5
  }

  .logoS {
  position: absolute;
  width: 37px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 58px;
  top: 17px;

  font-family: Von;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;

  color: #000000;

  z-index: 11;
  }

  .logoO {
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  left: 93px;
  top: 22px;

  border: 2.5px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border-radius: 50%;

  z-index: 11;
  }

  .home {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 69px;
  left: 770px;
  top: 12px;

  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;

  color: #000000;

  z-index: 11;
  }

  .work {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 69px;
  left: 993px;
  top: 12px;

  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;

  color: #000000;

  z-index: 11;
  }

  .about {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 69px;
  left: 1190px;
  top: 12px;

  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;

  color: #000000;

  z-index: 11;
  }

  .hi {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 244px;
  left: 390px;
  bottom: 3570px;

  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  z-index: 1;

  color: #373372;

  z-index: 3;
  }

  .Bilde img {
  position: relative;
  width: 1410px;
  bottom: 3660px;

  z-index: 1;
  }

  .workOverskrift{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  bottom: 7050px;
  left: 540px;


  font-family: Poppins;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;

  color: #DC95FF;

  }

 .appdesign{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4;
 bottom: 7150px;
 left: 600px;

 font-family: Poppins;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 36px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 0.04em;

 color: #373372;

 }

 .Hitesh img {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 7120px;
 width: 800px;
 left: 275px;
 z-index: 4;
 }

 .blurHitesh img {
 bottom: 7775px;
 width: 1000px;
 left:  225px;
 z-index: 3;
 }

 .arrowHøyre img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5;
 bottom: 8300px;
 left: 1180px;
 }

 .arrowVenstre img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5;
 bottom: 8476px;
 left: 92px;
 }

 .aboutOverskrift{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4;
 bottom: 8200px;
 left: 509px;

 font-family: Poppins;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 100px;
 line-height: 150px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 letter-spacing: 0.04em;

 color: #DC95FF;
 }

 .aboutTekst {
 position: relative;
 left: 316px;
 bottom: 8300px;
 z-index: 6;

 font-family: Poppins;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 72px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 0.04em;

 color: #000000;
 }`
```

Comment: The brackets on your CSS are off and your HTML isn't valid - have you tried running this through a formatter/linter?

Comment: Also, your `bakgrunn` element is 3840px tall - I don't know what your website looks like but I'm guessing this is one of the problem areas.

Comment: you have non-closed html tag `<h1>Hi There!<h1>` in addition to what @JamesWhiteley said about the CSS.

Comment: try making a snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/, and give a link back here, to let other members help you better

Comment: I tried formatting now. And I couldnt make jsfiddle file to work properly. But made a video, you can check it out here. To see how the webpage looks. https://imgur.com/a/HhFjsb2